# Issue on passwd generator

Tags: python-3.x, random, passwords, generator

I have issue with a code for generate password (code below)

```
from random import randint, choice

alphabet_min = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]
alphabet_maj = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
chiffre = [chr(i) for i in range(48, 58)]
carac_spec = [chr(i) for i in range(33, 48)]


def pwd(n, min1=True, maj=True, chif= True, cs=True):
    alphabets = dict()
    key = 0
    if min1:
        alphabets[key] = alphabet_min
        key += 1
    if maj:
        alphabets[key] = alphabet_maj
        key += 1
    if chif:
        alphabets[key] = chiffre
        key += 1
    if cs:
        alphabets[key] = carac_spec
        key += 1

    mdp = ' '
    for i in range(n):
        clef = randint(0, key - 1)
        mdp += choice(alphabets[clef])

    return mdp
```

When I execute this, nothing appear

Code finding on internet and very beginner in Python code.

Anyone have an idea of the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing anything.
You display stuff in console by using print() statements
For example

```
print("hello")
```

shows

```
hello
```

In this case you want to "print" the return value of pwd function

```
print(pwd(10))
```

The 10 is the first argument "n" so in this case the length of a generated password, by changing this number you will get different lengths.

Generally StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, please try to learn basics of language on your own, then try to google problems, and only then if google won't help, post questions here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't call the function! To call a function, type the name of the function followed by parameters. For example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

add(1, 2)
```

But there still is a problem. If you are running this in the IDE, Google Colab, or a Jupyter notebook, you probably would see `3` in the console. However, if you are running this in replit.com, mu, or a python IDE file, nothing appears. Now, you need to call `print()`. The solution to your problem is:

```
from random import randint, choice

alphabet_min = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]
alphabet_maj = [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
chiffre = [chr(i) for i in range(48, 58)]
carac_spec = [chr(i) for i in range(33, 48)]


def pwd(n, min1=True, maj=True, chif= True, cs=True):
    alphabets = dict()
    key = 0
    if min1:
        alphabets[key] = alphabet_min
        key += 1
    if maj:
        alphabets[key] = alphabet_maj
        key += 1
    if chif:
        alphabets[key] = chiffre
        key += 1
    if cs:
        alphabets[key] = carac_spec
        key += 1

    mdp = ' '
    for i in range(n):
        clef = randint(0, key - 1)
        mdp += choice(alphabets[clef])

    return mdp

print(pwd(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly code working with adding this at the beginning

```
n = int(input('\nEntrer la longueur du Mdp '))
```

and code `print(pwd(n))` at the bottom

Thanks for the help